# active record joins with distinct record

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an Event model with multiple time slots(on and from attributes both are datetime)

I need to get distinct events based on some condition that is applied on the time slot model through joins and have is sorted in some order.

I tried a few approaches but it just works when i order on the event attribute and not on the time slot attribute.

```
Event.joins(:time_slots).order('time_slots.from asc').distinct
```

throws InvalidColumnReference error

```
Event.joins(:time_slots).order('events.id asc').distinct
```

works

How can I make the former query work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use `Event.includes` instead of `Event.joins`, and it actually worked  as expected.